# Meson build: Specify output directories

Tags: meson-build

I have a c++ project that builds shared libraries, it also has a few binaries for packing resources into single files and trans-compiling few things into files easier for the library to process during runtime. To test the project I have a few tests. Earlier I used to use handwritten makefiles to build the following structure:

```
build/
  lib/
  bin/
  tests/
src/
  graphics/
  ui/
  util/
  network
```

As the names suggest, the source files are in src/, .so files go in build/lib/, the helper binaries go in build/bin/ and the tests go in build/tests.

I have managed to get meson to build everything, however it builds everything in build/. How do I specify the output paths in the targets?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a way to specify installation directories, or a way to structure build output directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check official documentation for installation [here](https://mesonbuild.com/Installing.html).
You need to provide `install` and `install_dir`

`executable('prog', 'prog.c', install : true, install_dir : 'my/special/dir')`

What I usually do for tests is to make `meson.build` in tests directory and then call `subdir('tests')` from top level `meson.build`. Here is the structure:

```
── meson.build

└── test
    ├── meson.build

    ├── component_tests

    │   └── meson.build

    └── unit_tests

        └── meson.build
```